# Determine parameter of the convergent sequence

Tags: calculus, analysis

How to determine parameter $\alpha$ in the given sequence so that the sequence is convergent:

$$a_{n}=\frac{3^n+(-2)^n}{3^{n+1}+(-2)^{n+1}}+(\frac{n+1}{n-1})^n+(1+\alpha)\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}$$

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill up details:

The first two summands of the sequence converge:

$$\frac{3^n+(-2)^n}{3^{n+1}+(-2)^{n+1}}=\frac13\cdot\frac{1+\left(-\frac23\right)^n}{1+\left(-\frac23\right)^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac13$$

$$\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac2{n-1}\right)^{n-1}\left(1+\frac2{n-1}\right)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e^2\cdot1=e^2$$

Thus, the whole sequence converges iff the last summand converges and this happens iff it vanishes, so *it must be that* $\; \alpha=-1\;$.

Further hint for the last part's **divergence**: check the last summand's subsequences for $\;n=2,4,6,...\;$ , and then for $\;n=1,5,9,13,...\;$ , and $\;\alpha\neq-1\;$